# Proof that a function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose $f$ is a joint probability density function of random variables $X$ and $Y$. $Y$ is integrable. I need to prove that the function $g(x) = \int_{\Bbb R} f(x,y)ydy$ is measurable function. I can't directly use Fubini here. How to proceed here ?

Also, I need to prove that $g(X)$ is integrable

Comment: "I can't directly use Fubini here" Meaning that you are not allowed to? In any case, what you are asking (measurability and integral 1) is exactly (Tonelli's version of) Fubini.

Comment: @Did: I don't see why. There is a $y$ in the integrand. So, non-negativity fails.

Comment: OK, then forget Tonelli and use Fubini. What else?

Comment: @Did: Please read the question "carefully" before answering. Here we have to use Fubini and Tonnelli both to prove that $g(x)$ is integrable. Hence it is measurable.

Comment: @Did: I am learning these things newly. The technique of showing measurability by showing integrability is new to me.

Comment: Your "Fubini and Tonelli both" comment (but Tonelli with only one n please) is a mystery to me. What are you trying to say exactly? Anyway, "showing measurability by showing integrability" is quite new, and I certainly did not suggest such an approach (whatever it might mean). Finally, if ever you find the time, please answer my very first question: why not use Fubini?